# Image from Gallery or Camera posting in ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-imageview, image-gallery

I have and android app that allow the user to choose an image from gallery or by capturing by the camera and when I get the single selected/captured photo I put it in my fixed sized imageView with 250dp width and 250dp height.

The problem is it is running in my Emulator but when I installed my app in real device, the posting of photo in imageView doesn't work. How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance

[Those 3 "+" are the Image View. This is screen cap from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbCeo.png)

[I select and capture 3 photo and paste it in my Image view, I also want to fit the image in my ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF7iu.png)

When I run this app in my real device the error comes up after capturing photo. The error is NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you update this question with more details (code, error, stacktrace, ...)?

Comment: I already edited my question

Comment: Post logcat and the code of the photo capturing. Device's os version?